# Azure Logic App - run SQL Server stored procedure on a schedule - nothing happens

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I have the simplest possible setup: on schedule there needs to be a stored procedure executed in a SQL Server database.

Now, I have this in App Designer:

[image]

and then there's this:

[image]

So clearly something is wrong or missing. Yet I have no idea what. Connection string to the SQL works - checked it's correct and besides, the stored procedure name is selected from a dropdown...

There are no errors of any kind (which is not surprising since trigger is not firing) anywhere. Only thing I have is this:

[image]

I've looked up several tutorials on how to do it and everything seems legit. I have good experience with different software with same functionality and I literally can't see what can go wrong in such a simple setup. What is most funny troubleshooting this setup shows zeros in every box, and yet it doesn't see the problem. But never mind, this is just a fun-fact.

But it's not working, clearly. Why?

Comment: Can you please help us with what output you are receiving from recent runs?

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT - That is the problem: no output whatsoever, nothing, except for the notification (I included screenshot of it in the Question) that it apparently worked. I have an impression this actually works but there's a step or a condition missing.

Comment: As you have set the sliding Window trigger to be triggered for 2 hours it takes 2 hrs to trigger your workflow. You can try reducing the time or you can hit run as mentioned this image https://i.imgur.com/l759jyn.png

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT - But it's set to start yesterday, so it should run at least 12 times since then. Hitting "Run Trigger" > "Run" does nothing, as well.

Comment: Can you please navigate to the Overview page of your logic app and check under Run History. https://i.imgur.com/fEiEqYC.png Because I could able to get this done with the same workflow as yours

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT - I just wanted to reply I included that screenshot in Q, too, but I decided to make it a better screenshot and lo! - there was a successful execution there, timestamped 4 min after I posted this Question... Then I went to the designer and ran the trigger manually.... And it timed out (with notification). So I created similar job in another subscription and it worked no issues - with only diff being Recurrence instead of Sliding WIndow. I made that change in sub from this Q and it works now... Weird. Case closed, I guess.

Comment: Can you please add the same in the answer section? just if anyone faces the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In case someone encounters similar problem, here's some observations from my issue.

First, the logic needs to be correctly saved - that is, it needs to run at least once in Designer, so that you'll get green checkmarks on all steps. This should be confirmed by notification that "Save logic app completed". In my case this "test run" was failing due to a time out and while I could and did save the logic, this could have been not enough.

Secondly, there may be some unexpected interaction between the trigger and the action in logic. In my case I wanted Sliding Window Schedule to execute stored procedure on SQL Server. This procedure doesn't return any output except for standard SQL Server 0 (zero) for success, and depending on SQL Server load it may run any time between 8 and 20 sec. While I have little evidence to support my suspicions (except for below - in "Thirdly"), I think the trigger was timing out waiting for SQL Server reply.

Thirdly, just for confirmation, I created similar logic on a different subscription, but instead of Sliding Window I used Recurrence and body of the stored procedure was just `Select 1`. It ran instantly when testing in designer and runs without issues since then. I changed the Trigger type in the original subscription to Recurrence (without any parameters except Interval and Frequency), tested and it runs well, too.

I have no clue as for the reason for the problem. Maybe a bug in Sliding Window, maybe something else, maybe it was timezone issue - I don't know. But it got solved and, while it's not enough for current stage (Testing), it will be more than sufficient when it will go to production, so I'll cope.